# Xcode 11 syntax highlighting broken for one project

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm struggling to fix a problem that started recently with my Swift Package Manager project. In Xcode 11, my files are only basically highlighted (i.e. keywords, string literals, and numbers) but full syntax coloring doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried deleting the project's Derived Data. The project fully compiles fine; it's just the coloring that's broken. I'm not using a `.xcodeproj`; I'm using Xcode 11's new SPM integration.

The weird thing is that the packages I've included have perfectly working coloring. It's just the source files for my package specifically whose syntax coloring is broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(This problem started during my use of Xcode 11 beta 6 and is still present in the current build of Xcode 11 from the App Store.)

Comment: Not sure if it'll be of any use or if its the same issue - but I've noticed that if I've got one of my frameworks open in one Xcode window, and an app which is using that frameworks in another Xcode window with a file from that framework selected - then none of the syntax highlighting will work for the files of that framwork

Answer (score 2):

I recommend trying this procedure:

1. right click on the file -> click 'delete'
2. click 'remove reference', this will remove the reference of the file but won't delete the file.
3. right click on other file in the same hierarchy -> click 'show in finder'
4. re-add the file you have removed reference in #2
5. re-indexing will begin and syntax highlighting works again.